# Plotly Dash: Show variable value in output

Tags: python, data-visualization, dashboard, plotly-dash

I am trying to make a dashboard with plotly Dash using COVID-19 dataset available from here: https://github.com/RamiKrispin/coronavirus-csv

Now, I want to show summary for the country selected through dropdown menu. But, I can't figure out how to just display the variable value.

I have done this for the total summary like this:
[Summary using just HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1udK2.png)

```
html.Div([html.H1('Summary'),

                              html.Div([html.H2('Confirmed'), 
                                        html.H2(t_confirmed)
                                       ], style = {'width': '30%','display': 'inline-block', 'border':'2px solid black', 'text-align' : 'center', 'font-family': 'Century Gothic'}),
                              html.Div([html.H2('Recovered'), 
                                        html.H2(t_recovered)
                                       ], style = {'width': '30%','display': 'inline-block', 'border':'2px solid black', 'text-align' : 'center', 'font-family': 'Century Gothic'}),
                              html.Div([html.H2('Deaths'), 
                                        html.H2(t_deaths)
                                       ], style = {'width': '30%','display': 'inline-block', 'border':'2px solid black', 'text-align' : 'center', 'font-family': 'Century Gothic'}),

                             ], style = {'width': '50%','display': 'inline-block', 'vertical-align' : 'top', 'font-family' : 'Century Gothic'})
```

What I want is, the values should change according to the country selected. I have the code and function which returns these values to me according to country. No idea how to display them. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you need are [Dash Callbacks](https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks). These allows you to dynamically alter the appearance of your components when you interact with them. Scroll down and have a look at the "Multiple Outputs" section - that might be similar to what you are trying to do. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying. What I want is, for example, when we type print("Total deaths:", <variable_name>) and it prints Total deaths: 1000. I know how to output graphs in dash. dcc.Graph(id = 'some_name', figure = fig_name) 

Similarly, what do I use to output variable value is my question. I hope its a little clear now!

Answer (score 0):

You can use an f string like so, in the `app.layout`, and your `html` tag and within it put `f'Total deaths: {variable_name}'`